# Can I trade my Gen 1 Gameboy Pokemon all the way up to Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-series

I recently rediscovered my old Pokemon Red game complete with my original Pikachu that I trained while I was a kid. What I'd like to do is try to trade it to my Sun game that I've just recently purchased using the intermediary gens and hardware as required.

I'm curious if it's even possible to get my Gen 1 Pikachu up to Sun. Any games, hardware, or software is fair game for this little project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is only possible with the Virtual Console version of the first generation games.

The Pokémon data format changed significantly in 3rd generation, so the two were incompatible. The GBA link cable and Gameboy link cable functionalities are fundamentally incompatible.